# How to split string with variables values separated by "/" and "," into different columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have data set of Ecommerce Bookstore in which there is a column Book name containing the name of the books purchased by customers in a single column (separated by `,` & `/`). I want to divide the Books into different columns. For example Book1, Book2 Book3, etc.

I know this is do-able using

`df[['Book1','Book2']] = df['Book Name'].apply( lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split("/")))`

But I don't know how many columns do I need to separate them.

Comment: Sample input and output please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split column into unknown number of columns according to number of words- Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62635214/split-column-into-unknown-number-of-columns-according-to-number-of-words-pandas)

Comment: From the dupes - just more concrete:  `df = pd.concat([df, df["Book Name"].str.split(r"[,/]", expand=True)], axis=1)` using a regex to split your existing column and concatting it back to your df - afterwards do a column renaming (see f.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas) - the trick here is to use the `expand=True` param.